# All elements are outside the containers after migrating TYPO3 version and gridelements

Tags: typo3-9.x, tx-gridelements

I am in the process of migrating our website from TYPO3 version 8 LTS to 9.5 LTS.

I have problems with gridelements (old version 8.7, new version 9.81).

Everything is correct in FE but **when I add content in BE** the tx_gridelements_container, tx_gridelements_columns, and colpos fields are at 0.

All elements are outside the containers (at the top of the page).

The drag and drop works very well.

Any suggestions or changes I haven't seen.

Comment: Finally, I was wrong.  tx_gridelements_container and tx_gridelements_columns was Ok.  only colPos was at 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a TypoScript snippet in our site

```
TCEFORM {
  tt_content {
    colPos.keepItems = 1,0,2
  }
}
```

keepItems -1 was missing.